# Balls in urn conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An urn contains 5 red, 7 green, and 8 blue balls. Three times in a row, we pick a random ball (uniformly) from the urn and then a) replace  or b) not replace it.

If the first two balls have the same color, what is the probability that the third ball also has the
same color?

What is the probability of this scenario for with replacement or without replacement. I am confused on this one as I tried just summing the probabilities and I got 100% for without replacement which is obviously not right. I think it has something to do with conditional probability, but I'm confused as to how I would use that.

Comment: The given condition $A$ is that the first two balls have the same color, the event $B$ is that all three balls have the same color.  So you want $$P[B|A] = \frac{P[B \cap A]}{P[A]}$$

Comment: @Michael So then would the probability for, red for example, be (5/20)^3/(5/20)^2. In which case it is 5/20 and when summed up with the others, 8/20, 7/20 would equal 20/20. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to compute $P[B \cap A]$ and then compute $P[A]$, and then divide them. The incorrect computation you are doing is like wondering why $$ \frac{1+2+3}{4 + 5 + 6} \neq \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{6}$$